# homeomorphisms of the real line

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, hyperbolic-geometry

Given a homeomorphism $h$ of the extended real line.

Is it true that there exists an extension $\hat h$ of $h$, which is a Mobius transformation of a hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}$?

Any hints are welcome! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There is an infinite-dimensional space of homeomorphisms of the circle; the space of Mobius transformations is the 3-dimensional $PSL_2(\Bbb R)$. But more pointedly, the restriction of a Mobius transformation to the ideal boundary can have at most two fixed points if it's not the identity; but any closed subset of $S^1$ is the set of fixed points of some homeomorphism.

Comment: A simpler reason is that there are homeos which are not smooth.

Comment: @Mariano Or that are not projectively linear ;D